# ¿como hacer un login dependiendo de una sucursal y usuario?

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-forms

Tengo el siguiente codigo para abrir mi login:

```
public class DCusuario:ConexionBD
{
    public bool Login(string usuario, string pass)
        {
            using (var conexion = ObtenerConexion())
            {   
                    conexion.Open();
                    using (var SqlComando = new SqlCommand())
                    {
                        SqlComando.Connection = conexion;
                        SqlComando.CommandText = "SELECT * from Usuarios where UsuarioLogin=@usuarioLogin and PassW=@pass";                        
                        SqlComando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usuarioLogin", usuario);
                        SqlComando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", pass);
                        SqlComando.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                        SqlDataReader reader = SqlComando.ExecuteReader();

                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return false;
                    }                             
               }                      
            }
}
```

¿Pero como hago para que dependiendo de la sucursal al que esta asociado ese usuario me abra la siguiente ventana, y que los datos que me muestre sea asociados al usuario y a la sucursal? Todos van a tener el mismo menu, lo que va a cambiar es la información que ven, quiere decir que si el **usuario 1** esta asociado a la **empresa 1**, solo va a ver los datos de esa **empresa 1** y si el **usuario 2** ingresa y esta asociado a **empresa 2**, solo va a ver los datos de la **empresa 2** y no de la **empresa 1** y si el **usuario 3** esta asociado a **empresa 1** y **empresa 2**, que vea ambos datos, no se si esto ultimo se pueda hacer.

De antemano gracias por tomarse el tiempo de leer y explicarme, utilizo `C#` y `sql server` como motor de base de datos. Trabajo a 3 capas.

**Nueva Edición**

Esta es mi tabla usuarios

[image: Tabla Usuarios]

Comment: Deberias agregar la columna de idEmpresa a las tablas que quieres traer los datos unicamente de esa empresa. Tambien hiciste una pregunta y agregaste otro codigo, ya que no tienes problema con el login o conexion sino con la informacion que quieres mostrar segun el usuario y empresa.

Comment: De antemano creo que es una pregunta demasiado amplia. Por otro lado deberías tener una clase `usuario` con todas las características del mismo. Y cuando, en la aplicación, realices una búsqueda de clientes, deberías filtrar la consulta por las empresas que te devuelva la clase usuario.

Comment: Para traer los datos de la empresa unicamente debes filtrarlo por el id de esa empresa y usuario. En las tablas que consultas esos datos, deberias tener una columna donde tengas un idEmpresa por ejemplo. El codigo que pones como ejemplo no tiene nada que ver con lo que necesitas.

Comment: Deberias poner como ejemplo la tabla que quieres filtrar, para ver los campos y ayudarte con la consulta o el diagrama de la tabla y base de datos

Comment: @RamiroBarone ok, ya entendi lo que quisiste decir, no he creado una tabla de empresa, porque no se como se haria en la consulta

Comment: @RamiroBarone  lo que entiendo que me dices es que todas las tablas que cree, tienen que tener el IdEmpresa para que se muestren como quiero, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero partiendo de que tenes una base de datos normalizada con Id primario y foreano, para relacionar las tablas, luego tus busquedas. Debes adaptar esta idea a las tablas que debes implementar con sus datos.
Notaras que coloque el IdEmpresa en cada tabla que cargues datos y luego necesites filtrar esos datos por empresa o sucursal puede cambiar el nombre pero no la idea. El usuario tambien perteneceria a una empresa o sucursal.

```
Create table Empresa(
Id int primary key identity (1,1),
Nombre varchar(100),
)

Create table Producto(
Id int primary key identity (1,1),
NombreProducto varchar(100),
IdEmpresa int not null

constraint fk_idempresa foreign key (IdEmpresa) references Empresa(Id)
)
Create table Clientes(
Id int primary key identity (1,1),
NombreCliente varchar(100),
IdEmpresa int not null
constraint fk_idempresa foreign key (IdEmpresa) references Empresa(Id)
)

Create table Usuario(
IdUsuario int primary key identity (1,1),
UsuarioLogin varchar(100),
PassW varchar(100),
Nombre varchar(100),
Apellido varchar(100),
Posicion varchar(100),
Email varchar(100),
IdEmpresa int not null
constraint fk_idempresa foreign key (IdEmpresa) references Empresa(Id)
)
```

//Luego con el id de la empresa que te debe devolver el usuario le pasas ese id a la consulta de las otras tablas que estan relacionadas con un ID.

```
SqlComando.CommandText = "SELECT * from Producto where IdEmpresa= @IdEmpresa"; 

SqlComando.CommandText = "SELECT * from Clientes where IdEmpresa= @IdEmpresa";
```

Para un mejor rendimiento no traigas toda la informacion con `*` si no necesitas todas las columnas.

Comment: muchas gracias, eso era lo que no entendia si era así, por cierto si voy a editar por ejemplo un producto, tambien tengo que colocar a en la condicion que sea igual al id del producto y al id de empresa?

Comment: Depende de como normalices tu tabla productos. Si el producto aplica igual para todos las empresas editas un solo producto, pero si el mismo producto tiene distintos precios para cada empresa, deberias buscar por idProducto e IdEmpresa